# openwrt network config error and IPv6 URL with interface name

Tags: networking, ipv6, openwrt

I wrongly configured my openwrt and lost access to my router. Using wireshark I discovered an IPv6 IP packet and can now ssh into it using only IPv6 IP address. But not from any browser.

Problem 1: I can though use `lynx [fe80::eade:27ff:feed:8634%en6]` and see LEDE login but I cannot do the same in any browser in Mac.

Problem 2: I don't know how to configure the network of my openwrt so that I can login into LEDE from a browser.

My router is not listing to 192.168.3.5. I had configured it as a bridge between my phone wireless to ethernet. Now its all gone wrong.

Dump of /etc/config/network:

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd11:c5ac:cf22::/48'

config interface 'lan'
    option _orig_ifname 'eth0 radio0.network1'
    option _orig_bridge 'true'
    option proto 'static'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option ipaddr '192.168.3.5'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'

config interface 'ethernet'
    option _orig_ifname 'eth0'
    option _orig_bridge 'false'
    option proto 'dhcp'
    option type 'bridge'

config interface 'XYZZenfone'
    option proto 'dhcp'
    option _orig_ifname 'wlan0'
    option _orig_bridge 'true'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option hostname 'LEDEStatic'

config interface 'XYZZenfone2'
    option proto 'dhcp'
    option type 'bridge'

config interface 'repeater_bridge'
    option proto 'relay'
    list network 'XYZZenfone2'
    list network 'lan'
```

Please suggest fixes in this network config so it takes a static IPv4 address listening to port 80 so that I can use it on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Graphical web browsers don't allow accessing a site via a *link-local* IPv6 address literal in the URL.

You can work around this by giving the address a name and placing it in your computer's hosts file, which is at `/private/etc/hosts` on macOS. You will need to use `sudo` to edit it. An example configuration:

```
fe80::eade:27ff:feed:8634%en6 myrouter
```

Now you can go to `http://myrouter/` in Safari (or any other browser) and access the router.